# Django - how to create a form field containing checkboxes WITH an 'Other' text input field

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm creating a form in Django, and would like to give users a list of checkboxes with the option of having an Other _____ text input as one of the choices. Here's my code using `MultipleChoiceField` and `CheckboxSelectMultiple`:

```py
class IntakeFormSimple(Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IntakeFormSimple, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    preferred_pronouns = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=(("she/her", "she/her"), ("he/him", "he/him"), ("they/them", "they/them")),  # <--- add "Other" here
        label="What are your preferred pronoun(s)?",
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `CharField` or `TextField` instead of `MultipleChoiceField`. Then you need to create a custom widget which is a combination of `MultipleSelect` and `TextInput` widgets. I suggest using a `MultiWidget` to add these two widgets together (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/#multiwidget) and adding the "Other" checkbox purely decoratively which uses some JS to enable/disable the text input. To do this you will need to use custom widget template.

I am suspecting that you will also need to override the field class too to make it work with your custom widget.

I hope I pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "other" field to your Form:

```
class IntakeFormSimple(Form):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(IntakeFormSimple, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

preferred_pronouns = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    choices=(("she/her", "she/her"), ("he/him", "he/him"), ("they/them", "they/them", "other")), 
    label="What are your preferred pronoun(s)?",
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
)
```

Now in your javascript file, hide that input when page loads:

```
$("#user-input-textbox").hide();
```

Finally, use the 'other' radio button is checked and hide it when it is unchecked and also clear the existing value before hiding:

```
    $('#Other').click(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            $("#user-input-textbox").show();
        }
        else{
             $("#user-input-textbox").html('');
             $("#user-input-textbox").hide();
        }
    });
```